# Mule inbound endpoint keeps logging errors when writeToDirectory is called and file exists in the destination folder with the same name

Tags: java, filesystems, mule, scheduled-tasks

I'm using mule version 3.5.0. in a Java web application.
I use the mule xml configuration and defined a file:inbound-endpoint:

```
<file:inbound-endpoint path="${home.dir}/out" moveToDirectory="${home.dir}/out/hist" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="input"/>
```

with the connector being:

```
<file:connector name="input" fileAge="10000" streaming="false" autoDelete="false">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.file.FileMuleMessageFactory" />
</file:connector>
```

Now I have the problem that when I want to move a file to the directory that contains already a file with the same name, an error is thrown in mule and is repeated continuously, generating +1GB logfiles:

```
[[hip].input.receiver.05] 18:33:55,234 [ERROR]        org.mule.exception.AbstractExceptionListener.logException(AbstractExceptionListener.java:307) - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000003.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000003.xml".  The file might already exist.
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-11004
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to move file     "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000003.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000003.xml".  The file might already exist. (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException)
org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver:561 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/DefaultMuleException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException: Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000003.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000003.xml".  The file might already exist.
at     org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.moveAndDelete(FileMessageReceiver.java:561)
at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.access$100(FileMessageReceiver.java:58)
at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver$2.process(FileMessageReceiver.java:433)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

[[hip].input.receiver.05] 18:33:55,240 [ERROR] org.mule.exception.AbstractExceptionListener.logException(AbstractExceptionListener.java:307) - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000004.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000004.xml".  The file might already exist.
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-11004
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000004.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000004.xml".  The file might already exist. (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException)
org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver:561 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/DefaultMuleException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException: Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000004.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000004.xml".  The file might already exist.
at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.moveAndDelete(FileMessageReceiver.java:561)
at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.access$100(FileMessageReceiver.java:58)
at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver$2.process(FileMessageReceiver.java:433)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

[[hip].input.receiver.05] 18:33:55,242 [ERROR] org.mule.exception.AbstractExceptionListener.logException(AbstractExceptionListener.java:307) - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000005.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000005.xml".  The file might already exist.
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-11004
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000005.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000005.xml".  The file might already exist. (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException)
org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver:561 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/DefaultMuleException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException: Failed to move file "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\0.A.REQD.00000000000005.xml" to "D:\hip\batch\taxiAsService\out\hist\0.A.REQD.00000000000005.xml".  The file might already exist.
at   org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.moveAndDelete(FileMessageReceiver.java:561)
at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.access$100(FileMessageReceiver.java:58)
at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver$2.process(FileMessageReceiver.java:433)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Is there a way to:

- limit the logging? Like that it is only displayed one?
- Can I eventually overwrite the existing file?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for the excessive logging is because you have the **autoDelete** property to ***false***. So, because the move operation is failing (and the source file is not being deleted), the flow is polling the source file recursively.

The workaround would be to set the **autoDelete** to ***true*** and use the **file:outbound-endpoint** to write the source file content into the out directory (instead of using the **moveToDirectory** property in the inbound-endpoint). This way you can customize the destination filename to avoid writing existing files.